# Augmented Reality Desktop Application using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, desktop-application, augmented-reality, 3dsmax

Can we create an augmented reality desktop application using unity which can convert all images from a school textbook into 3D objects. ? If yes, then what will be the procedure and what other tools do we need. ? It is our final year project and we really need help in this.

Comment: Augmented Reality and Desktop Applications are antonyms. They whole concept of AR is to capture the movement of the device which is the reason there is next to no libraries for desktop AR (I can't be sure though). Why not mobile?

Comment: @NikaKasradze basically we are working on a concept of converting 2D images of a textbook into 3D through AR because students are not allowed smartphones in class.

Comment: What do you mean by "can convert all images from a school textbook into 3D objects"? You mean that you have one 2D image or photography of a car and it automatically converts that image into 3D model?

Comment: I meant to say that the pictures of a particular topic would act as markers for the 3D models that will be linked with these images..

Comment: Wouldn't using a device be easier tho?

Answer (score 1):

If watermark will not be an issue than you can use Vuforia library.

https://developer.vuforia.com/

It has nice unity integration and you can archive what you are up to in almost no time :). But it is not supporting desktop build out of the box, but below you have alternative libraries that do:

http://artoolkit.org/download-artoolkit-sdk#unity

http://www.easyar.com/view/download.html

I can't say how good they are because I have never used them.

Comment: And can Vuforia support desktop application building as well ?

Comment: I have used it with web cam in editor, I have newer build an executable desktop app but I think it should work. 
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/using-vuforia-ar-for-standalone-application.165343/
In this topic there is example of Vuforia app working on desktop,

Comment: Ok I will try this one.. Thank You :)

Comment: No, vuforia does not support desktop application for now.

Comment: Confirm, you can only debug in Editor, but you cannot build. That would not fit a school usage since it would mean users are using Unity with a open project containing Vuforia.

Comment: @fafase exactly that the target is to create a desktop application that can be accessed by students in school using pcs and webcam.

Answer (score 1):

You can try artoolkit, stable and simple. Easyar is good but a little young.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ARToolKit. You can target OSX, Windows and Linux if you need to. Also using the Unity plugin it should be easy for you to get started. 
And if you decide to go on mobile later it also has support for iOS and Android.

http://artoolkit.org/download-artoolkit-sdk
(Scroll down for Unity version)

Edit:
They also have an active forum where you can ask questions and find help if you have the need:
http://artoolkit.org/community/forums/

Best